# Очистка объекта типа IEnumerable полученный через PropertyInfo

Tags: c#, рефлексия, ienumerable, ienumerator

Проблема в очистки списка приведенному к IEnumerable полученный через рефлексию с помощью `PropertyInfo`

часть кода получения и приведения к типу:

```
PropertyInfo[] p = ele.GetType().GetProperties();

Object obj = p[i].GetValue(ele, null);

if (obj is IEnumerable<Object>)
{
    IEnumerable<Object> ie = (obj as IEnumerable<Object>);
    if (ie == null)
           return;

    // часть 1-я: чистит локально, поскольку копия, в структуре данные сохраняются
    ie.ToList().Clear();
    // часть 2-я: Создание нового объекта и замещение
    var x = new IEnumerable<object>();
    p[i].SetValue(ele, x, null);
// Вот тут происходит exception про несоответствие типов,
// например Ienumerable<object> невозможно преобразовать в List<string>
}
```

Как правильно очистить IEnumerable/List через рефлексию? При чем тип `<ХХХ>` может быть разный.
Возможно надо как то более тонко детерминировать тип, а не приводить к `IEnumerable<object>`?

Comment: `var x = ie.ToList().Clear();` что вы хотели присвоить в `x` ?

Comment: пустой элемент, можно конечно попробовать создать заново и присвоить, но на результат это не влияет. Если вы про то что он очищает список и не возвращает, то это не совсем так, он очищает копию, в структуре остаться данные. В примере накосячил :)

Comment: ну вы не сможете очистить IEnumerable, если у свойства есть сеттер, то можно присвоить новый IEnumerable, а если сеттера нет, то нельзя. Если там List то можно вызвать `Clear`, но и то не факт, что это повлияет на следующий вызов геттера

Comment: не совсем понятно чего ты именно хотел добиться этим кодом и из-за этого не совсем ясен контекст. Попробуй почитать про структуру dinamic возможно тебе это поможет

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если под "Очистить" понимается "Вызвать метод Clear() через позднее связывание или упасть, если его нету", то как-то так:

```
Type RuntimeType = obj.GetType();
MethodInfo method = RuntimeType.GetMethod("Clear");
if (method == null) throw new ApplicationException("Object type does not have Clear() method!");
else method.Invoke(obj, new object[] { });
```

---

Если под "Очистить" понимается "Присвоить свойству значение новой пустой коллекции", то как-то так:

```
static bool IsIEnumerable(Type t)
{
    if (!t.IsGenericType) return false;
    Type InterfType = typeof(IEnumerable<>);
    if (t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == InterfType) return true;

    foreach (Type it in t.GetInterfaces())
    {
        if (it.IsGenericType && it.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == InterfType) return true;
    }

    return false;
}

static void ClearIEnumerable(PropertyInfo prop, object obj)
{
    Type PropType = prop.PropertyType;
    if (!IsIEnumerable(PropType)) throw new ArgumentException("Property is not IEnumerable<T>");

    Type InnerType = PropType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    Type ListType;
    if (PropType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
        ListType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(InnerType);
    else
        ListType = PropType;

    object new_val = Activator.CreateInstance(ListType);
    prop.SetValue(obj, new_val);
}
```

Comment: Тогда уж `(obj as dynamic).Clear()`. Это будет даже быстрее работать при частых вызовах...

Comment: Спасибо, но с рефлексией это не поможет, к сожалению.

Comment: А из каких соображений `typeof(IEnumerable<int>)` именно int?

Comment: @NewView Это я перемудрил что-то. Там можно вместо этого прописать просто `typeof(IEnumerable<>)` и сразу получить generic definition. Обновил ответ.

Comment: Да, вроде так правильней, спасибо за решение

Comment: Погоняв немного в реальных условиях, выяснилось что код `if (it.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == InterfType) return true;` надо оборачивать в `try/catch` поскольку оно там кидает исключения `InvalidOperationException` - `Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object`, неготово оно еще. Для тех кто __соберется повторить__ этот код.

Comment: @NewView Скорее нужно добавить проверку it.IsGenericType. Я не учел, что generic-тип может реализовывать не-generic интерфейсы. Обновил.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight,  А ведь точно!

Answer (score 5):

`IEnumerable`- это `ReadOnly` тип, который нельзя очистить => вам нужно найти источник.
Например, за "кулисами" - это может выглядеть так:

```
private List<string> _list
public IEnumerable<string> Strings=>_list
```

Ну это самый простой пример, так как данные вообще могут браться через вызов какого-то свойства вложенного типа => нужно бегать по всем вложенным типам и по косвенным признакам искать источник, что не реально, так как может быть произвольное кол-во абстракций.

Да, вы можете привести `Strings` к типу `List`, но это будет не реальная коллекция, а ее копия.

Т.е задача, труднореализуемая.

Comment: А пути решения? уверен что можно очистить список полученный с помощью рефлексии..

Comment: Ну получили вы список и материализовали его через ToList. Какой смысл его очищать, если он не очистится у исходного объекта? В таком случае что мешает вам создать сразу пустой список нужного типа?

Comment: Я писал об этом, можно и новый, но тип должен совпадать, а не быть приведенным к IEnumerable, а вот как это организовать, прямых путей я не нашел, другими словами, как получить истинный тип.

Comment: Вы хотите конкретный тип коллекции получить, которая прячется за интерфейсом ?

Comment: По сути наверно да, хочется получить то, чем можно заместить оригинал с помощью SetValue

Comment: А вы не сможете так просто заместить тип. В общем случае, как я сказал, задача не решаема. В конкретном случае, когда известно внутреннее представление класса - это можно решить, но это не совсем правильно. В общем- это путь в некуда.

Comment: Мысли то есть, через CreateInstance, MakeGenericType. Но предполагалось есть наработанные решения без изобретения велосипеда :) пойду пробывать собрать велосипед :)

Answer (score 0):

Решение все-же есть как очистить объект типа IEnumerable полученный через рефлексию.
Уверен, в нем наверняка есть подводные камни..

Как это реализовать:

```
    private Object GetIEnumerableEle(PropertyInfo p, ref bool IsIenumerable)
    {
        Type[] t0;
        Type t1 = ((p == null) ? null : p.PropertyType),
             t2, t3;
        Object ie = null;
        IsIenumerable = false;

        if ((t1 != null) && (t1.IsGenericType))
        {
            t2 = p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();

            if ((t2 != null) && ((t2 == typeof(List<>)) || (t2 == typeof(IEnumerable<>))))
            {
                IsIenumerable = true;

                if (
                    ((t0 = t1.GetGenericArguments()) == null) ||
                    (t0[0] == null)
                   )
                    return ie;

                if ((t3 = t2.MakeGenericType(t0[0])) == null)
                    return ie;

                return Activator.CreateInstance(t3);
            }
        }
        return ie;
    }
```

Как этим пользоваться:

```
    PropertyInfo[] p = ...;

    if (p[n].PropertyType.IsGenericType)
    {
        bool IsIenumerable = false;
        Object ie = GetIEnumerableEle(p[n], ref IsIenumerable);

        if ((IsIenumerable) && (ie != null))
            p[n].SetValue(obj, ie, null);
    }
```

Ларчик то несложно открывался :)

Comment: Но этот код не работает, если тип свойства - IEnumerable<T>, так как нельзя создать экземпляр интерфейса. Этот способ работает, только если тип свойства - List<T>, но в этом случае вы просто можете вызвать Clear(). Я добавил в свой ответ способ, который работает и для IEnumerable, и для List

Comment: Спасибо, смотрю